# jQuery Mobile header included in content wrap

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, panel

**EDIT: It would seem all I needed to do was add `data-position="fixed"` to the header and that ensured it was encapsulated by a separate wrapper than content.**

According to the panels docs, a panel must be a sibling of the header, content and footer elements within a page. So this is my basic markup (heavily stripped down):

```html
<body>
    <div data-role="panel"></div>
    <div data-role="header"></div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer"></div>
</body>
```

However, when JQM re-renders the DOM, it creates this:

```html
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="panel"></div>
        <div class="ui-panel-content-wrap ...">
            <div data-role="header"></div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
           <div data-role="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, it wraps the header, content and footer in the content wrap instead of just the content. How can I force it to behave correctly?

Comment: How do you expect it to behave.I don't observe anything wrong.Jquery mobile pages are wrapped within the page div.Can you please specify where exactly the issue arises.

Comment: The page was created fine, but the header was meant to be in a separate wrapper from the content wrapper. As you will see in my edit at the top I just needed to specify that the header be fixed.